# SVG Scrolling fill

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I'm trying to alter the fill of an SVG as the page is scrolled? 
I've got it working but when the height of the window is changed the scroll offset doesn't work as desired.

I want the scroll line to match the fill line.

Jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/11x3cwnr/

I think the problem is the calculation here:

```
  document.getElementById("SVGID_1_").setAttribute("y1", 93000 + progress * 93000);
```

Any ideas?

Cheers

Comment: FYI I took some help from this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7gzzddks/

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "I want the scroll line to match the fill line."  Can you elaborate, or add some images to show what you mean?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Basically as you scroll up or down, the scroll line changes in height, thus leaving a gap between the 2 variations of image. I will try and add some images to show what I mean.

Comment: If you set the height of the 'result's' window to the height of the image, you will see the desired effect of the scroll. But if you set the results window to be larger than the image, you will see the scroll has a incrementing gap within in the gradient. Any ideas?